# What is the pro's and con's of locking the actual file vs an empty lock file?

Tags: unix

My program is writing to a binary file, and there could be multiple instances of the program accessing the same binary file for the same user. In Unix/Linux, I see some programs (particularly daemon processes) locking an empty lock file instead of the actual shared data that needs to be locked (so instead of locking `~/.data/foo` they lock `~/.data/foo.lck`). What are the pros and cons of locking the actual file vs an empty lock file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flock` is not supported over NFS or other network file systems for all version of unix (it wasn't even supported by Linux until 2.6.12). On the other hand `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` is much more reliable over many more file systems, and has been so for much longer.

Even on systems that do support `flock` on network filesystems (or cases where you don't need that flexibility), `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` together with `flock` is very useful because it distinguishes between a clean shutdown and a non-clean shutdown. `flock` helpfully goes away automatically, but it also, unhelpfully, doesn't distinguish *why* it went away.

flocking the file itself prevents atomic writes (copy, erase old, rename), or any other case where you might erase the existing file. Sometimes "the actual file" doesn't always have the same inode over the entire run of the program. So a separate file is much more convenient in those cases as well. This is very common in those `foo.lck` cases, because often you're locking `foo` for a short period of time, and might erase it in the process.

Comment: Thanks, the history lesson is insightful on why lock files exist.

Answer (score 1):

I see three cons of an empty lock file:

- The user permissions of the directory should allow you to create a file.
- In case of disk space issues, this might fail.
- In case your program crashes, the lockfile is still present.

I see one con of modifying the actual file's name:

- In case your program crashes, your file has been altered (only the filename, but it might generate confusion).

Obviously, I see one big advantage of the empty lock file:

- your original file does not change at all.

By the way, I believe this question is better suited for the [SoftwareEngineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) community.

Comment: Thanks. Some comments. empty's con #2: in a lot of cases when disk is full, I think an empty file can still be created because it only add an item to the directory's inode instead of allocating a new inode. empty's con #3 is surely a con, but not a serious one. actual con #1: I think this is orthogonal to the issue of locking; this is an issue of atomic write and should be solved by using a temporary file. empty's pro #1: I'm not sure I follow. Surely when I issue a lock my intention to modify the data (the original file) regardless of which file I'm locking.

Comment: Also thanks about the community suggestion. Didn't know it exists.